# How do I find the number of order of a specific number in a sequence of numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

So I have a task in university. I have to write a Java program which allows to to input numbers starting from 0 and the specific count of said numbers. Then the numbers are arranged in an increasing order. If there is a number which equals zero then the output must be the number of order of the zero. If there are more than one zeros then the output must be the number of order of the last zero. If there are not any zeros, then the output is zero. I have to specifically use recursions.

I have pretty much done everything, but I have a problem with finding the zeros.

For example if I input numbers 2, 3, 4 then the output will be 0, because there aren't any zeros. If I input 0, 1, 2 the output will be 1, because that is the number of order of the zero. But if I input 1, 2, 0 or 2, 0, 0 and etc. then something goes wrong and outputs 0. For example if the numbers are 1, 2, 0 then the output should be 1, because the numbers are arranged in an increasing order and the number of order of the zero is 1.

Here is my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    static Scanner sc; 
    public static int[] a;
    
    public static void inputArr(int i) {
        if (i < a.length) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
            inputArr(i+1);
        }
    }

  public static boolean checkNum(int i) {
        if (i < a.length-1) {
            if (a[i] <= a[i+1])
                return checkNum(i+1);
            else 
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

  public static int checkZero (int i) {
    checkNum(0);
    if (a[i] == 0) return 1+checkZero(i+1);
    else return 0;
  }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int count;
        System.out.print("count:");
        count = sc.nextInt();
        a = new int[count];
        
        System.out.println("numbers:");
        inputArr(0); 

    System.out.print("result: ");
    boolean result = checkNum(0);
    int zero = checkZero(0);
    System.out.print(zero);

    
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why tag it with `javascript`?

Comment: A Java program is not a *script*, and it certainly isn't JavaScript (a completely different language).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for clarifying, still learning :)

Comment: @flyingfox didn't know the difference, thanks for calling out that mistake